# NSIS, how to keep a label over a text control after it is clicked?

Tags: user-interface, controls, label, nsis, nsdialogs

I got this code,

```
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0

; Link
${NSD_CreateLabel} 292, 301, 71, 18 "click here!"
Pop $0
SetCtlColors $0 0x0000FF 0xFFFFFF ; Blue on white
${NSD_OnClick} $0 on_click_link

; Text area
nsDialogs::CreateControl /NOUNLOAD ${__NSD_Text_CLASS} ${DEFAULT_STYLES}|${WS_CLIPCHILDREN}|${WS_TABSTOP}|${ES_WANTRETURN}|${ES_MULTILINE} ${__NSD_Text_EXSTYLE} 5 220 660 115 ''
Pop $1
SendMessage $1 ${EM_SETREADONLY} 1 0
SetCtlColors $1 0x000000 0xFFFFFF ; Black on white
${NSD_SetText} $1 "A label(hyperlink) is put over this text area"

nsDialogs::Show
```

I went the label to stay on top of the text control.
When I click on the text area of the text control, the label disappear.
**Is there a way to tell the label to stay over the text control ?**

Please help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting Z-order of label with **SetWindowsPos** function call.

Use HWND_TOPMOST to set max Z-order of label, here is API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx